# I can't get the timer to display

Tags: javascript, timer

I cannot get the timer countdown to display at all.

I've tried console logging but idk. I'm a noob.

```
var game = {
correct: 0,
incorrect: 0,
countdown: 90,

countdown: function () {
    game.countdown--;
    $("#counter-number").html(game.countdown);
    if (game.countdown === 0) {
        alert("Out of Time!");
        game.done();
        console.log(countdown)
    }
},
// Can't get counter to stay on screen
start: function () {
    timer = setInterval(game.countdown, 1000);
    $('#insidecontainer').prepend('<h2>Time Remaining: <span id="counter-number">90</span> Seconds</h2>');
    $("#start").remove();
    console.log(timer)

    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        panel.append('<h2>' + questions[i].question + '</h2>');
        for (var j = 0; j < questions[i].choices.length; j++) {
            panel.append('<input type="radio" name ="question' + '-' + i + '"value="' + questions[i].choices[j] + '">' + questions[i].choices[j]);
        }
    }
    panel.append("<button id='done'>Done!</button>");
},
```

The timer comes up as 90 but then disappears after 1 second. I want the timer to display it's counting down until it gets to zero.

Comment: You have conflicting property. game.countdown cannot be a timer and a function at the same time, i.e. game.count = 90, game.countdown = function() {}

Answer (score 0):

The questions is missing a lot of code but there are various ways to implement timer with JS and JS libraries.

Following your approach maybe something like this would be sufficient?

```
var game = {
  correct: 0,
  incorrect: 0,
  countdownseconds: 90,
  intervalId: null,

  countdown: function () {
    game.countdownseconds--;
    if (game.countdownseconds === 0)
      clearInterval(game.intervalId);
    $("#counter-number").html(game.countdownseconds);
  },

  start: function () {
    $('#insidecontainer').prepend('<h2>Time Remaining: <span id="counter-number">90</span> Seconds</h2>');
    game.intervalId = setInterval(game.countdown, 1000);
  }
}
game.start();
```

As `jimmy5312` pointed out there was collision with the identifier `countdown` so I used `countdownseconds` to hold the seconds.

Using this approach, most of your logic would go to `countdown` function, but I think you should still be able to to extract another function to handle the business logic for the questions and call it right after `$("#counter-number").html(game.countdownseconds);`